# django logged in userprofile and relating additional form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have question regarding how to attach additional form to logged in users in Django.
I want that additional form belongs to logged in user and the data I enter in the form should goes under logged in user table. I am new to Django and python please have patience I hope i can explain correctly what i want to do with this

Data I shall enter for this view shall go under logged in user only basically i want to attach this view to the logged in user only  Error I am getting is 
Exception Value:

registration_todos.user_id may not be NULL

```
#models

class userProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth =models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class todos(models.Model):
    user     = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created  = models.DateField()
    time     = models.TimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.user)

#forms   additional form for todos  
    class formtodos(ModelForm):
        title       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Todo'))
        created     = forms.DateField(label=(u'Date'))
        time        = forms.TimeField(label=(u'Time'))
        #user        = forms.CharField(label=(u'username'))
            class Meta:
               model = todos
               exclude=('user',) 
#view  
 def modeltodo(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
    todos.objects.filter(user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form =formtodos(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():# All validation rules pass
        todoss = form.save(commit=False)
        todoss.created_by = request.user
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
else:
    form = formtodos() # An unbound form

context = {'form':form}
return render_to_response('todo.html', context,    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've specified `exclude = ('user',)` in your form. This means that when you try to save the form there is no `user_id` present which causes the error. You probably want to put this before the `save()` call: `todoss.user = request.user`

Comment: Thank you very much this has made me very frustrated while i was missing this :) Can you provide me some document link where i can easily understand this concept :)

Comment: well everything you need should be in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ Basically the fields in your form map 1-1 to the attributes of your model. When you are creating a form for the todoss object (BTW you should use standard naming conventions and change that to Todo) you exclude the `user` field (obviously you want this to be `request.user` and don't want the user to be able to change this). However when you run `form.save()` the form is missing the user data  which causes the error. Supplying this avoids the error.